# Array pointer to the attribute of an array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, attributes

I have the following struct and main function:

```
struct myStruct{
    string name;
    int id;
    int group;
};

int main(){
    myStruct student[5]; // The struct student has an array of 5 elements
    search(student, 1, 33);  // We pass the struct student with all the 5 elements
}
```

I want to pass a struct to the function search, and then make an array pointer that stores the value of a certain attribute, but of all the arrays of the struct.

*e is pointing to student, with all the arrays(5), so if type equals 1 the pointer is going to point to all the values of the attribute of each array of the structure e

```
void search(myStruct *e, int type, int value){
    if (type == 1)  int *ptr[] = e[0]->id;   //An int pointer because the id is an int
    if (type == 2)  int *ptr[] = e[0]->group;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(*ptr[i] == value){
           cout << e[i]->name << endl;
           cout << e[i]->id << endl;
           cout << e[i]->group << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I want `*ptr[]` pointing to each array of the attribute depending on the parameter passed in type. Ex:

> `if ( type == 1 )`
>
> `ptr[0] = e[0].id;`
>   `ptr[1] = e[1].id;`
>   `ptr[2] = e[2].id;`
>   `ptr[3] = e[3].id;`
>   `ptr[4] = e[4].id;`
>
> **^Notice that is just the id**
>
> `if ( type == 2 )`
>
> `ptr[0] = e[0].group;`
>   `ptr[1] = e[1].group;`
>   `ptr[2] = e[2].group;`
>   `ptr[3] = e[3].group;`
>   `ptr[4] = e[4].group;`
>
> **^Notice that is just the group**

The problem is that I can't find a way to do that, the real struct in my program has more than just three attributes, it actually has eight, so it will be a waste of code if I do a case for each one.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand this question. The sample code you provide doesn't compile.

Comment: `student` is not "a struct". It is an array of 5 "structs", _at best_. Watch your terminology!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a "pointer to member". Note: This isn't an array of pointers, but rather a pointer that you can only use with an object of the class.

Also note: this is reasonably advanced, so you might want to get normal pointers straight in your head first.

```
void search(myStruct *e, int type, int value) {
    int myStruct::*ptr;   // ptr is a pointer to a member variable of an object
    if (type == 1)  ptr = &myStruct::id;
    if (type == 2)  ptr = &myStruct::group;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (e[i].*ptr == value){          // access the value of the current object using ptr.
            cout << e[i].name << endl;    // Note that you had these accesses wrong.
            cout << e[i].id << endl;
            cout << e[i].group << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very hack approach that is somewhat low-level and only applies to POD struct type whose attributes are of the same type (e.g., int) and stored continuously.

Suppose your struct looks like this:

```
struct myStruct {
  string name;
  int attr1;
  int attr2;
  ...
  int attr8;
}
```

You can write your search function as follow:

```
void search(myStruct *e, int type, int value) {
  int *ptr[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    int *base = &e[i].attr1; // treat attr1...attr8 as an int array
    ptr[i] = &base[type - 1];

    if (*ptr[i] == value) {
      cout << e[i].name << endl;
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        cout << base[j] << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```